# is it possible to split ArrayCollection in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

im trying split arrayCollection and copy into another arrayCollection. Is it possible .any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use addAll method for adding one IList to another.

```
myCollection.addAll(anotherCollection);
```

Comment: This leaves you with a reference to the first object?

Comment: Not sure that I've understood your question. 
References both to myCollection and anotherCollection will remain the same.

Comment: I'm trying to say is that I think the two ArrayCollection stay with the same reference, then would cease to be a copy, maybe Eranga Lakmal Perera need a clone or copy dereferenced, to work independent of the data source.

Comment: I see. Fortunately you can always clone items in advance:

var newAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( anotherCollection.source ) );

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Why was my question because you have to make a clone of a class to another by reflection ArrayCollection.

Comment: Wait, so you want to have the same instance of items in both collections? 
I suppose you can do it like that:
myCollection.source.push(anotherCollection.source[0]);
But you can not push range.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918194/how-can-i-copy-an-arraycollection-of-transfer-objects-in-actionscript

Comment: Ah, yes) Sorry, the topic starter was asking simular question in another topic. And there he wanted to avoid using iterations.